# Compilation error : Changing Depricated @Data in package "org.eclipse.xtend.lib" to "org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.Data" - Xtend 2.7.2

Tags: xtext, xtend

I migrated xtext from 2.6.0 to 2.7.2 . After migration we had compilation errors related to `@Data` in package `org.eclipse.xtend.lib` . This annotation was depreciated and it was pointing to new annotations from `'org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.Data'` .  But still its not compiling

Below is the trace for the same .

```
Error during annotation processing:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro.TransformationContext.isThePrimaryGeneratedJavaElement(Lorg/eclipse/xtend/lib/macro/declaration/Element;)Z
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.DataProcessor$Util$1.apply(DataProcessor.java:64)
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.DataProcessor$Util$1.apply(DataProcessor.java:1)
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.internal.BooleanFunctionDelegate.apply(BooleanFunctionDelegate.java:40)
com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:702)
com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.IterableExtensions.forEach(IterableExtensions.java:398)
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.DataProcessor.doTransform(DataProcessor.java:97)
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro.AbstractClassProcessor.doTransform(AbstractClassProcessor.java:42)
```

Regards
Srinivas

Comment: It appears to me that you run the annotation against an old version of the lib.macro bundle. Are you sure that no old artifacts are used or on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `org.eclipse.xtend.lib` to classpath!

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Its already there in class path , But still facing this problem :(

Comment: it actually is org.eclipse.xtend.lib

Comment: so making a hint to a imperative makes it better?